# What is the best way to detect and redirect a mobile browsser in AppEngine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, mobile-phones, mobile-website

Specfically, I am working in Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check it out @mobiforge : http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/creating-mobile-web-sites-with-google-app-engine

Answer (score 0):

set your doctype to

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.0//EN" "http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd">
```